# Copy tables from different worksheet in excel and paste it in existing presentation

Tags: vba, excel

I have a specific excel workbook which has tables in different worksheets in different range.I want tables should be automatically copied from all the worksheet of my excel workbook and should be pasted in different slides of my existing ppt template.

I have created a code but giving error on range which I want to copy:

```
Sub newpp()
    Dim pptapp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim preslide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim shapepp As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim exappli As Excel.Application
    Dim exworkb As Workbook
    Dim xlwksht As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim myshape As Object
    Dim mychart As ChartObject
    Dim lastrow1 As Long
    Dim lastcolumn1 As Long
    Dim slidecount As Long

    'Open powerpoint application
    Set exappli = New Excel.Application
    exappli.Visible = True

    'activate powerpoint application
    Set pptapp = New PowerPoint.Application
    pptapp.Visible = True
    pptapp.Activate

    'open the excel you wish to use
    Set exworkb = exappli.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ap\Desktop\Macro\Reference Sheet.xlsm")

    'open the presentation you wish to use
    Set pres = pptapp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\ap\Desktop\Macro\new template.pptx")
    'Add title to the first slide
    With pres.Slides(1)
        If Not .Shapes.HasTitle Then
            Set shapepp = .Shapes.AddTitle
            Else: Set shapepp = .Shapes.Title
        End If
        With shapepp
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Gulf+ Market Segment Analysis Report" & vbNewLine & "P5 Week 04 FY17"
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial Black"
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 24
            .TextEffect.FontBold = msoTrue
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
        End With
    End With
    'set the range

    lastrow1 = exworkb.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastcolumn1 = exworkb.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For Each xlwksht In exworkb.Worksheets
    xlwksht.Select Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0.00:1"))
    **'getting error in this line-------**
    exworkb.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).CopyPicture appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    slidecount = pres.Slides.Count

    Set preslide = pres.Slides.Add(slidecount + 1, 12)

    preslide.Select

    preslide.Shapes.Paste.Select

    pptapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignTops, msoTrue
    pptapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 65
    pptapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 72
    pptapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 700

    Next xlwksht

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `For Each xlwksht In exworkb.Worksheets` loop with the modified loop below.

I made the following modifications to your code (so it will work):

1. Instead of `Selecting` the worksheet and then use `ActiveSheet`, use `xlwksht`, I've added the `With xlwksht`.
2. You need to search for the last row and column for each worksheet, so I've moved it inside the `With` statement.
3. There is no need to `Select` the slide every time in order to paste.
4. Some other modifications...

**Modified For loop Code**

```
For Each xlwksht In exworkb.Worksheets
    With xlwksht
        lastrow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastcolumn1 = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        ' set the range
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).CopyPicture appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

        Set preslide = pres.Slides.Add(pres.Slides.Count + 1, 12) ' <-- set the Slide

        preslide.Shapes.Paste
        With preslide.Shapes(preslide.Shapes.Count) '<-- modify the pasted shape properties
            .Top = 65
            .Left = 72
            ' etc...
        End With

    End With
Next xlwksht
```

Comment: @astha  you're welcome, please mark as "Answer" (click the **V** next to my answer )

Comment: Just one question there are 12 tables which I am copying on the PPT slide  . Currently each of the table is positioned at the same place based on the alignment code which I have specified. Is there a way that I can give separate alignment code for each chart. Eg first chart at top right corner on slide 1, second chart at the centre of slide 2, third chart at top left corner and so onn....

Comment: I have clicked it, will it be possible for you to guide me on my second question stated above

Comment: you can. but then it's not inside this `For Each xlwksht In`... loop, you will need to modify each one manually (that's a lot of code lines)

Comment: Thanks for the help yes I will do seperate coding to align my charts. I just wanted to know one more thing in case I want to align it to top right corner how we set the dimensions is there any referring module which you can suggest from where I can learn aligning my charts and tables because I want to learn the alignment dimensions of any figure in PPT. For eg. if it says .Left = 40 what does that mean.

Comment: It means 40 point ms from the left, 72 points equals one inch

Comment: Is there any learning module which you can refer to me to learn how to align tables/charts in Powerpoint slides through vba codes